# Validate first name and last name using a deep learning or machine learning model

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, nlp

I have around 1 million data points of first name and last name.
These names could be valid ones , for example : 'David Beckham' or invalid like - 'rockstar123' or 'new mutant'. Is there any deep learning / ML model which will allow me to differentiate amongst the 2 ?

Comment: Some kind of k-nearest-neighbour variant might be worth investigating.

Comment: But frankly I strongly advise you not to use this for anything related to real life. Administration is painful enough when it's enforced by humans. I've had friends and family members who were unable to send me letters because their local post system insisted my address was invalid. I've had trouble with administration my whole life because my first name is a foreign name that is close to a non-foreign name except spelled differently. It'd be sad if a promising student was refused entrance at university because a machine told them their name was not a valid name.

Comment: Do not underestimate the damage that can be done by a computer who blocks someone from going through a required process, because the computer insists the person's name is not a valid name. Not to mention it's insulting.

Comment: @Stef Thanks for you input . Some context here - We get user names from an ecom domain which sells used items. So i would basically want to identify the prob of a name being bad. There are some examples of names being 'TN23' , 'Fan:70953521' which are obviously not true names. I'm basically trying to estimate the features of these bad names v/s good ones. And this is currently for south east asian countries

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Option 1:** Use any pre-trained Named Entity Recognition (NER) model.
[image: Example]

**Option 2:** Train your custom NER model. Under the hood, different NER models use different embeddings (GloVe, Transformer-based, etc.). Once you have decided the embeddings for your task, any binary classification model can output the probability (e.g., naive-bayes, logistic regression, SVM, neural network).

**Option 3:** Don't use ML. For this simple task I would lean towards regex/[rule-matching](https://spacy.io/usage/rule-based-matching).